# Adding a button to favorites that inserts javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've seen a few sites offer a tool that allows users to drag a button to their favorites bar and then when they click on it, no matter what site they are on, a div of some form would pop up on the page. When I looked at the url of the button that I had dragged onto my favorites bar, I realized that it was actually javascript code.

How is this effect accomplished?

Comment: Is there a question here? Not really sure what you're asking.

Comment: Your right sorry for not wording it as a question. I meant does anyone know how it is done?

Answer (score 3):

This is called a "bookmarklet".  You can create a hyperlink that contains the necessary JavaScript code, which they drag into their bookmark toolbar.

It is as simple as creating a hyperlink on your page containing the JavaScript as its `href`.  For example:

```
<a href='javascript:alert("you clicked a bookmarklet");'>Drag me to your bookmarks</a>
```

[See it in action at JSFiddle...](http://jsfiddle.net/wGYbq/1/)

In order to make it look like a button, CSS is applied (borders, background color, etc.).

Comment: This works great, is there a way to add html to the page using something like innerhtml? Also would there be a way to use jquery?

Comment: @Ian34 Probably not jQuery, unless someone else can prove me wrong.  You can modify `innerHTML`. See http://jsfiddle.net/wGYbq/4/

Comment: Couldn't you use `document.write` to add a `script` tag which references a jquery library, then go from here?

Comment: I tried to use document.write to add a div to the page but instead it removes all content from the page and only keeps the div See http://jsfiddle.net/PMmAn/11/

Comment: @Ian34 That's how `document.write` works. You would need to use `document.createElement()` to build a new node and `document.appendChild()` (or `appendChild()` on some specific element) to add to an existing document. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.createElement

Comment: So would it be like this: http://jsfiddle.net/PMmAn/22/`<a href='javascript:var newDiv=document.createElement("div");var newContent=document.createTextNode("Hi there and greetings!");newDiv.appendChild(newContent);'>Drag to Bar</a>`

Answer (score 0):

Try typing this in the location bar of your browser, when you press return the javascript will execute automatically:

```
javascript:alert('hi');
```

Bookmark 'scriptlets' work using the same notion. If you have an `<A>` tag as follows on your page:

```
<a href="javascript:alert('hi');" >Hello Scriptlet</a>
```

And you drag it onto your bookmarks bar, you'll create a scriptlet with the same behaviour.